# Why does gradle think it's 1970?

Tags: gradle, unix-timestamp

When I execute the following code:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew --profile --offline --rerun-tasks assembleDevelopmentDebug
```

[image]

Is there any way to correct the time and date?

Comment: I think you should optimize your build, the duration is a bit too long

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I needed to prepend `:app:` to the gradle task like this:

`./gradlew --profile --offline --rerun-tasks :app:assembleDevelopmentDebug`